# asp.net manipulate form field values using javascript but cannot get the value on server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net

currenly I worked on a project with heavy javascript, do all the logic at client side, that mean manipulate form field values using javascipt, but when I post back to server I cant get the value on server side. example below:

Aspx

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#<%= Label1.ClientId %>").html("200");
   </script>
```

code behind

```
  Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      Response.Write(Label1.Text)
   End Sub
```

I have manipulate the values using javascript, but when click the button post back, I still get "Label". I not sure whether is the viewstate issue, I have try to turn off the viewstate of the control but the result is still same.

Comment: I think this is to do with `Label` not implementing the `IPostBackDataHandler` interface... Can you use a different control? Yes it is to do with this, see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8181471/1402923

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick work around if the case is for single label then could keep that value in hiddenfield and post. Then it will be available in server. As mentioned if the code is there to keep the manipulated values in many labels and keeping hiddenfield for all those labels would be heavy. Could have a jquery ajax call to post the data instead of entire page post as a suggestion.

```
<input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" value ="manipulated value" />
```